# How to get the count from Unstructrued data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have unstructured data from my perf logs. I would like to capture the service details from it.  I can do delimiter, however I am not able to count or Print the column, since it doesn't have any header.

Kindly help me to figure out this issue.s

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv (r'/Users/Myhome/Documents/Py_Learning/log.csv', sep = '|' , skipinitialspace=True)
#df = pd.read_csv (r'/Users/Myhome/Documents/Py_Learning/log.csv', sep =':|,|[|]', engine='python', header=None) ---> Multi separator is giving error. 


#df.groupby("CLIENT")
SERVICE = df.columns[4]
print (SERVICE)
```

How can I find the unique service name in all lines and get the count. I would like to give it as a graph with last week data.

Sample data :

`2019-10-22 15:35|Where:CARD|SERVICE:Dell|VERSION:1.0|CLIENT:HDD|OPERATION:boverdue|RESPONSETIME:0034|STATUS:100000:ERR_TRANSACTION_TIMED_OUT|SEVERITY:ERROR|STATUSCODE:SOAP-FAULT|STATUSMESSAGE:NA 2019-10-22 15:35|Where:Digital|SERVICE:Laptop|VERSION:1.0|CLIENT:mouse|OPERATION:connet|RESPONSETIME:3456|STATUS:NO_RECORDS_MATCH_SELECTION_CRITERIA|SEVERITY:INFO|STATUSCODE:1120|STATUSMESSAGE:NA`

Comment: Are there newline characters (`\n`) following the dates always?

Comment: the solution depends on how multiple rows are shown, is the output from your dataframe, try `df.stack().str.split(':',expand=True).set_index(0).T` should get you pretty close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, since you're data has no header, you need to set `header=None`.

`df = pd.read_csv ('data.csv', sep = '|' , skipinitialspace=True, header=None)`

And then to get service data, simply do

`new_df = df.iloc[:,2].str.split(':', expand=True).iloc[:,1].value_counts()`

Comment: ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 13 fields in line 2, saw 14

Comment: @MariappanMurugan, can you provide a sample of your log file (not copy paste the content, but the file itself). I think there's some discrepancy between what you posted here vs the content of the file itself.

Comment: every one hr I am getting this raw data in a Notepad. I will try to attach it here...